# Can I trigger a Power Automate workflow from custom JavaSript?

Tags: javascript, power-automate

How can I start/trigger any flow from my custom JavaScript code?

I am not asking about the button flow, and not any Out of the Box feature, I just want to trigger my flow from my JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

Create the flow triggers by 'Request – when a HTTP request is received', you could find the script in [TechNet wiki page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52544.sharepoint-online-trigger-a-microsoft-flow-with-button-click.aspx).

```
function StartMicrosoftFlowTriggerOperations() { 
    try { 
        var dataTemplate = "{\r\n    \"emailaddress\":\"{0}\",\r\n    \"emailSubject\": \"{1}\",\r\n    \"emailBody\": \"{2}\"\r\n}"; 
        var httpPostUrl = "<Supply with the HTTP POST Url>"; 
        //Call FormatRow function and replace with the values supplied in input controls. 
        dataTemplate = dataTemplate.FormatRow($("#txtEmailAddress").val(), $("#txtEmailSubject").val(), $("#txtEmailBody").val());
         var settings = { 
            "async": true, 
            "crossDomain": true, 
            "url": httpPostUrl, 
            "method": "POST", 
            "headers": { 
                "content-type": "application/json", 
                "cache-control": "no-cache" 
            }, 
            "processData": false, 
            "data": dataTemplate 
        } 
        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) { 
            console.log("Successfully triggered the Microsoft Flow. "); 
        }); 
    } 
    catch (e) { 
        console.log("Error occurred in StartMicrosoftFlowTriggerOperations " + e.message); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This mean I have to add an Action of HTTP Request to get this code work? Right?

Comment: That's flow trigger condition, not Action.